# Error during building angular2-material bundle from source

Tags: angular, gulp, angular-material

I am trying to create [angular2-material](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material) bundle using below gulp task:

```
  gulp.task('bundle.js.material.dev', ['build.js.material'], function() {
  var devBundleConfig = {
    meta: {
      rx: { 
        build: false
      }
    },
    paths: {
        '*': 'dist/js/dev/es6/*.js'
    }
  }

  return bundler.bundle(
      devBundleConfig,
      'angular2_material/material - angular2/angular2',
      './dist/build/angular2_material.dev.js',
      { sourceMaps: true });
});
```

I am getting below error. Any idea on this??

> [00:23:26] 'bundle.js.material.dev' errored after 572 ms 
>   [00:23:26]Error: Error loading "angular2_material/material" at
>   file:/home/tapas/Work/Github/Angular/ng2/angular/dist/js/dev/es6/angular2_material/material.js
>   ENOENT, open
>   '/home/tapas/Work/Github/Angular/ng2/angular/dist/js/dev/es6/angular2_material/material.js'
>       at Error (native)

Comment: Here is an sample project that is already set up: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-examples

Answer (score 1):

Material in the Angular2 repository was just experimental. It was moved to https://github.com/angular/material2 recently.

See also https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/105

> We'll soon be publishing an alpha.0 to npm once a few more things are ready. The announcement will probably be on Twitter, so stay tuned!